# VCR gem - Can I store my response data in a separate JSON file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, vcr

Using the VCR gem, responses are saved as a large string inside the YAML cassette file. Like this:

```
 response:
    body:
      string: '{"data":{"salesforceObjects":{"records":[{"student":{"accountId" ...
```

However, is it possible to save this JSON in a separate file, which is properly formatted and easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

From official [docs](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-1/docs/cassettes/cassette-format#request/response-data-can-be-saved-as-json):

```rb
VCR.use_cassette('example', :serialize_with => :json) do
  puts response_body_for(:get, "http://localhost:7777/foo", nil, 'Accept-Encoding' => 'identity')
  puts response_body_for(:get, "http://localhost:7777/bar", nil, 'Accept-Encoding' => 'identity')
end
```

Comment: Which part of this snippet prints the JSON to a file? I am using seralize_with: :json but all this does is turn the whole cassette into JSON instead of yaml - The response is still an ugly string

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrote a custom cassette persister, like documented in here?

https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-1/docs/cassettes/cassette-persistence

You can read the response body and store it in a custom file. Then, upon reading, you add the response body stored to the cassette.
This might not even be required if you just want a pretty-formatted copy of the response for reference.

Something on the lines of: (not tested)

```
class PrettyCassetteBodyPersister

  # dunno if content is a string or hash. Might be missing some serialization / deserialization
  # might require extra logic to make it work with multiple request cassettes

  def [](name)
    content = YAML.load IO.binread("cassettes/#{name}")
    response_body = JSON.parse IO.binread("cassette_bodies/#{name}")

    content['response']['body'] = response_body
    content
  end

  def []=(name, content)
    IO.binwrite("cassettes/#{name}", content)
    IO.binwrite("cassette_bodies/#{name}", content['response']['body']
  end
end


VCR.configure do |c|

  c.cassette_persisters[:copy_bodies] = PrettyCassetteBodyPersister.new
  c.default_cassette_options = { :persist_with => :copy_bodies }
end
```